# pasar parametro del boton ala funcion

Tags: javascript

como pasar el parametro id al .filter, me sale undefined, probe lo que decian mas abajo el boton se muestra asi dependiendo del elemento seleccionado este numero aumenta o disminuye su valor

asi es el boyon en el html

```
 printf('<td class="td"><button  class="button" onclick="(e)=> addToCarritoItem(e,'. $e->id_productos . ')">Añadir</button></td>');

<button  class="button" onclick="(e)=>addToCarritoItem(e,15)">Añadir</button>


el segundo parametro es el que intento recuperar

    var arreglo=[]
        function addToCarritoItem(e,id){
          const button=e.target
            const item = button.closest('.tr');
    
            const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
          const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
          const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;
          
       
          const Productos = {
            id: id_prod,
            codigo: codigo,
            nombre: nombre
      
          }
        
          let itemProductos = Productos;
          arreglo.push(Productos)
        let itemProducto =arreglo.findLast(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
```

Comment: Estás usando las funciones `push()` y `filter()` sobre la variable `arreglo` que no está declarada en ningún lado dentro del código que muestras.

Comment: ya edite, sigue vacio

Comment: También estás usando una variable `item` que no está declarada en ningún sitio.

Comment: la funcion ```addToCarritoItem``` esta asociada a un evento? Si es asi, ese parametro ```id``` que estas definiendo seguramente no te va a funcionar. Prueba quitando el ```id``` y recupera el definiendo ```id = this.id```

Comment: Ahora se cual es el problema, pero me sale igual undefined, edite mi pregunta

Comment: Hola Felipe. No entiendo por que estas usando el findLast, si lo unico que queres es tomar el producto que acabas de agregar. Fijate que el id que estas intentando buscar es el producto que acabas de insertar.

Comment: find por lo que tengo entendido es de izquierda a derecha y lo que necesito es de derecha a izquierda(la busqueda), pero no logro captiurara ese numero id que le llega a la funcion, me sale undefined

Comment: @SaulUribe en q parte te refieres, puedes amplar tu pregunta, porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Realice unos cambios en tu código, intentando buscar resolver tu inconveniente. Espero te pueda ser o dar una idea de resolver.

```
//Dejando el id como 'data' dentro de la etiqueta button y td. Entiendo que es PHP lo que usas aqui
printf('<td class="td"><button  class="button" data-id="{$e->id_productos}" onclick="addToCarritoItem(event)">Añadir</button></td>');

<button  class="button" data-id="15" onclick="addToCarritoItem(event)">Añadir</button>


//el segundo parametro es el que intento recuperar

    var arreglo = [];

    function addToCarritoItem(e){
        const button=e.target
        const item = button.closest('.tr');
    
        const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
        const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
        const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;
          
        //Para acceder al 'data-id' usas this.dataset.id
       
        const Productos = {
            id: id_prod,      //<<--- el objeto se genera con 'id'
            codigo: codigo,
            nombre: nombre
        }
        
        let itemProductos = Productos;
        arreglo.push(Productos)

        //En el findLast el objeto es 'id' y no 'id_a'
        let itemProducto =arreglo.findLast(({id}) => id === this.dataset.id);
    }
```

Prueba y nos dejas saber tu resultado. Saludos